# Why is Ax = 0 to be even considered when finding the complete solution to Ax = B?

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

In this write-up, ["Homogeneous and non-homogeneous equations"](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m8s00/public_html/handouts/matrices2/node8.html), it says:

> If the matrix equation
>
> $\displaystyle AX = B$
>
> has one particular solution $ X_p$, and the associated homogeneous
>   equation
>
> $\displaystyle AX = 0$
>
> has the complete solution $ X_h$, then the complete solution to the
>   original non-homogeneous equation is
>
> $\displaystyle X = X_p + X_h.$

**Question:** What I do not understand is the motivation or intuition behind even attempting to look for the nullspace via $\displaystyle AX = 0$ when you already have not just one solution but an infinite number of solutions as the complete solution (via the parameter *t*) of a system of equations where there are more unknowns than equations! *(If needed, please see the Example that immediately follows in the write-up.)*

Comment: We can find all solutions to $AX=B$ directly, but $AX=0$ is much more studied and easier to handle, so any chance you get to reduce to the homogenous case is one you ought to take.

Comment: The solution of $AX=0$ is called the "kernel" of $A$ and has some useful properties ; for example, it is a vector-space. The structure of the solution $AX=0$ is therefore easier to grasp. Moreover, an analogue sum-equation is also useful in solving differential equation , for example.

Comment: @Arthur *"any chance you get"*? Not sure I follow you. I've been given only $Ax=B$ to solve, so why would I even look in the direction of $Ax=0$?! Do you mean, the RHS becoming all zeroes during Gaussian elimination? Even then, I don't understand the need for doing anything special or extra. That is, I get either 1 solution or an infinite number of them via free variables / parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the relevant excerpt of the referenced article more carefully this time.

It seems $Ax = B$ won't require venturing into nullspace solutions via $Ax = 0$ **provided** you express the solution as parameterized (when the system of equations has free variables).

The complete solution even in *Intro to Linear Algebra, 4ed* book by Strang, page 158, is something we can obtain just by solving $Ax = B$ and remembering to use parameters. In other words, the parameterized solution *is* the complete solution that includes in it the particular solution automatically.

The confusion, I think, arose because I failed to notice how some authors were arriving at their particular solution. They were setting free variables to 1, one at a time. But if you set them to parameters, $s$, $t$ etc from the get go, there would be no need to even mention nullspace and conceptually complicate things for newbies (like myself).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are solutions to $AX=B$, that is,
$$
AX_1=B
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
AX_2=B
$$
In particular, $AX_2=AX_1$, which implies $A(X_2-X_1)=0$, that is, $X_0=X_2-X_1$ is a solution to $AX=0$. Note that
$$
X_2=X_1+X_0
$$
so $X_2$ has the form “solution of $AX=B$ plus solution of $AX=0$”.

Conversely, if $X_p$ is a solution of $AX=B$ and $X_h$ is a solution of $AX=0$, then also $X_p+X_h$ is a solution of $AX=B$, because
$$
A(X_p+X_h)=AX_p+AX_h=B+0=B
$$

It's not difficult to complete the proof that *every* solution of $AX=B$ can be obtained as $X_p+X_h$ with $X_p$ a *fixed* particular solution of $AX=B$ and $X_h$ any solution of $AX=0$.

Another way to look at the subject is by considering linear maps. Suppose $A$ is $m\times n$; then we can define a linear map $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.

If $B\in\mathbb{R}^m$, then the set of solutions to $AX=B$ is precisely
$$
f^{-1}(\{B\})=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(X)=B\}
$$
If a solution $X_p$ exists, then
$$
f^{-1}(\{B\})=X_p+\ker f=\{X_p+X_h:X_h\in\ker f\}
$$

Comment: Hey thanks, but I'm still no better off.  In my understanding, a system has either no solution, or one solution or infinite solutions. So, how could you even start out assuming $X_1$ and $X_2$  to be the solutions to $Ax = B$?

Comment: If you got one solution then you start wondering if there is another solution. So you suppose that you have $X_1$ and $X_2$ as your solutions and try to relate the two solutions.

Comment: @Harry Mathematics always goes on like “If we suppose A, then we get B; let's see whether B implies A”.